# bash: how to compare strings with nums and letters?

Tags: string, bash, compare

I have an array the contains element like 1617b, 1516a and the like. I want to echo the elements in descending order-meaning the ones with the greatest number chars in them, and if identical the ones with bigger letter. Any idea on how to do this? Will a simple "if" work? As in:

```
if [[ ${array[$j]}>${array[$j+1]} ]]; then
     .
     .
     .
```

tnx in advance

Comment: I suggest to remove all trailing letters: `echo "${array[$j]/[a-z]*/}"`

Comment: yea but i still need to check the letters when i compare. i guess i can just use cut (there are always 4 numbers then one letter). but then how do i compare letters? does the shell know B is bigger than A, for example?

Comment: If there's always exactly 4 digits and 1 letter, lexicographic comparison should work fine, you don't need to split it into number and letter.

Comment: You can use the `sort` command instead of comparing strings in `bash`.

Comment: what is lexicographic comparison? sorry, i am new to bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way

```
$ ar=(1234a 2345b 1234c 4444d)
$ sorted=$(printf "%s\n" ${ar[@]} | sort | xargs)
$ echo $sorted

1234a 1234c 2345b 4444d
```

for descending order add `-r` flag to `sort`

if you want your sorted values back to an array

```
$ sorted_ar=($(printf "%s\n" ${ar[@]} | sort))
$ echo ${sorted_ar[@]}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `xargs` here? And shouldn't it be `sorted=($(...))` (with extra parens)?

Comment: yes, the first output is not an array, so to serialize the values on to the same line with `xargs`.  Added second option to convert values back to array, where `xargs` is not needed and added.

Comment: Oh, I get it now: it's to remove the newlines.